# bootstrap .btn-group-justified not work as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image: md]

[image: sm]

[image]

How can I get rid of questionmark filed??? I need to fill it by "button" with "another h3".
"h3 again" and "some h3" is below "another h3" and there is more of these.

My html:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-wrap btn-default">
                <h2>another h3</h2>
                <img class="/images/img4.png">

            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-wrap btn-default">
                <h2>h3 again</h2>
                <img class="imageClip" src="/images/img2.png">

            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-wrap btn-default">
                <h2>some h3</h2>
                <img class="imageClip" src="/images/img1.png">

            </a>
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have already achieved the default 480px breakpoint on XS, on this value it usually starts to break the elements and place them among themselves. 

You should customize the breakpoints - [customize media query breakpoints](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints)

As an alternative you can just expand your `h3` element to full width when the screen reaches 480px using a media query in your CSS.